# ssh port forwarding through a pseudo terminal

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, terminal, mysql

Here's a situation:

I do all my work on a Mac.

> 1. There's a certain linux server '*server01*' that provides access to
>      another linux server '*server02*' via a pseudo terminal
>
>    So, to ssh into '*server02*', I do this from my mac:
>
>    ```
>    ssh -t server01 'inline server02'
>    ```
> 2. Then it asks me for a password to '*server01*'; I enter it and that
>      logs me into '*server02*'. Now, I am on the '*server02*' terminal.
> 3. From '*server02*' I can access the mysql database that is sitting on
>      '*server03*' using the following mysql command:
>
>    ```
>    mysql --host=server03 --port=4201 --user=myuser --password=mypass mydb
>    ```
> 4. Neither '*server01*' nor '*server02*' or my mac have direct SSH access to '*server03*'

Now, I want to access the mysql on '*server03*' from my mac directly through some kind of port forwarding. So, if I type the below command on my mac terminal, it should connect me to the mysql database on '*server03*':

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=4201 --user=myuser --password=mypass mydb
```

Is there a way to do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not that it's a direct solution, but have you tried sshuttle? If you have access to Python, it makes it significantly easier to deal with this type of forwarding, and you'd be able to easily forward the MySQL traffic across each of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a chain of forwardings. First, connect to server1 and add a forward for SSH connections to server2:

```
mac% ssh -f -N -L 10022:server2:22 server1
```

(The `-f -N` options will make it run in background.)

Then connect to server 2 via that forward, and add a forward for MySQL connections to server 3:

```
mac% ssh -f -N -L 14201:server3:4201 -p 10022 -o HostkeyAlias=server2 localhost
```

(You're connecting to `localhost` port `10022`, and the earlier forward lets you reach server2. HostkeyAlias is optional, just some paranoia.)

Finally connect to server 3:

```
mac% mysql --host=localhost --port=14201 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got an error after running the second command. Here's the error:

channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Just to clarify, my mac doesn't have direct SSH access to server3

Comment: Do you have any further ideas as to how I can fix this error?